# I run multiple async tasks at once and I want to close only one of the three

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, android-asynctask

I run one asynctasks class 3 times in one of the activities and I was wondering how can I individually cancel one of them. Each one downloads a file from a server which is always a different file and I was wondering how can I cancel only one of the three which ever one I pick?

Comment: Oh, just an FYI, in Honeycomb & ICS the standard behaviour for AsyncTask was changed from allowing parallel tasks to a serial executor - you'd need to start your AsyncTasks using executeOnExecutor(Executor, Params...) instead of execute(Params...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep a reference to each of them, then provide a method in it to cancel them. Call that method on the one you want to cancel.

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    boolean cancelled = false;
    public void cancel() {
        cancelled = true;
    }

    public void doInBackground() {
        while(!cancelled) {
            ...
    }
    ...
}

...

MyAsyncTask task1 = new MyAsyncTask().execute();
MyAsyncTask task2 = new MyAsyncTask().execute();
MyAsyncTask task3 = new MyAsyncTask().execute();

...

if(needToCancelTask2) {
    task2.cancel();
}
```

Comment: This is completely **redundant** btw - AsyncTask already implements a proper cancelling method - AsyncTask#cancel(boolean), allowing you to also control if the worker thread should be interrupted. In the doInBackground implementation you typically check AsyncTask#isCancelled()

Comment: Hah! Too true. Nice catch, I don't know why I never noticed that.